# do while loop issues

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, do-while

This code is for a button of a basic grocery calculator. When I push the button an input dialog box shows where you enter your item price. The problem I am having is that I cannot figure out how to get a `do ... while` loop to make the input dialog pop back up after an entry is made.

I want it to always come back up unless the user selects ok with nothing, or cancel, in which case the loop should break and fill the remaining boxes. With the current code I have to push the button to bring the dialog back up manually each time. I have been playing around with different while conditions and if statements but I cannot seem to get it to work. I am a beginner so sorry if this is simple, and thank you for your time.

NOTE: I left the while condition empty on purpose, just showing thats where I need it.

```
  NumberFormat numForm = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
  double itemPrice;
  double tax;

  do {
    String s = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter item price:");
    if (s == null || s.equals("")) { 
        double subtotal = getPurchase();
        double total;
        tax = subtotal * .065;
        txtTax.setText(numForm.format(tax));
        total = tax + subtotal;
        txtTotal.setText(numForm.format(total));
    } else {
        try {
            itemPrice = Double.parseDouble (s);
            recordPurchase(itemPrice);
            txtPrice.setText(numForm.format(itemPrice));

            double subtotal = getPurchase();     

            txtSubtotal.setText(numForm.format(subtotal));
            int items = getItems();
            String totalItems = Integer.toString(items);
            txtItems.setText(totalItems);

        } // end try
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You must enter numeric data only!");
        } // end catch
      } // end if Else
    }// end do
    while();
```

Comment: Does it have to pop back up or clear itself `onClick`? IOW, is it really necessary to do it that way? Additionally you need a condition for your `while();` to check.

Comment: @BobbyDigital I just need it to pop back up, ready for another entry. Then when okay with nothing is clicked, or cancel, it breaks the loop then populates the last three boxes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put a condition in your while statement.  If the condition is true, it will keep iterating.

```
String s = "";
do 
{
    s = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter item price:");
    if (s == null || s.equals("")) 
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}while(s != null || !s.equals(""));
```

Comment: That won't work, you're declaring a new String inside the `do`. Should just be `s = ..` inside the `do` not `String s = ..`

Comment: I know i left the while loop blank on purpose because none of mine worked. thank you for your answer but unfortunately, I get errors. It tells me string s is already defined even when i put the String s = ""; outside of the loop

Comment: @Devin, just delete the `String` part of the `String s` that is inside the `do`

Comment: @peeskillet, your approach did work, everything works how its supposed to but I am getting an error when I hit cancel, and I am unsure of where to break the loop so that when I hit ok the box goes away

Comment: @SamIAm Might be good to note that `s.isEmpty()` works just as well as `!s.equals("")` or even `s.length()==0`

Comment: Problem solved, added a break at the end of the IF. Thank you all for your help I really appreciate it.

Comment: If you are already checking `s == null || s.equals("")` once you might as well make it a `while (true)` and call break during the first check. Otherwise you are making the same checks twice. Your while condition should also be `&&` not `||`. With `||` you will get a NPE if the user hits cancel.

Answer (score 1):

This might read nicer as a `while`?

```
String s;
while ((s = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter item price:")) != null) {
    if (s.isEmpty()) { break; }
    try {
        itemPrice = Double.parseDouble (s);
        recordPurchase(itemPrice);
        txtPrice.setText(numForm.format(itemPrice));

        double subtotal = getPurchase();     

        txtSubtotal.setText(numForm.format(subtotal));
        int items = getItems();
        String totalItems = Integer.toString(items);
        txtItems.setText(totalItems);

    } 
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You must enter numeric data only!");
    }
}

double subtotal = getPurchase();
double total;
tax = subtotal * .065;
txtTax.setText(numForm.format(tax));
total = tax + subtotal;
txtTotal.setText(numForm.format(total));
```

This way the code that executes at the end is shown that way visually.

Answer (score 0):

```
 do {
    String s = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter item price:");
    //user has pressed the cancel button then s becomes null
    if(s == null){
        break;
    }
    // your code

    }
 while(true);
```